# Nginx redirection within the same domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application server which is running on Tomcat. In front of it there is an nginx proxy with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.net;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/example.net.ssl.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/example.net.ssl.error.log;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
    }
}
```

I am trying to configure redirection from **example.net** to **example.net/test/page** so that any user who requested **example.net** will be redirected to **example.net/test/page**.

I have tried to use **return** and **rewrite**. Also changed **proxy_pass** to the required page, for example:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/test/page;
```

All these tries were without a success. I would really appreciate any advice or solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect the request to your mentioned URL. Add this:

```
location = / {
    return 301 http://localhost:8090/test/page;
}
```